# Spanish audio or video resources to practise shadowing

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, pronunciation, spanish

I am looking for audio and/or video resources in Spanish (as spoken in Spain, not Latin America) to practise shadowing. **Shadowing** is a technique that involves listening to audio and simultaneously speaking out loud the words you hear. The goal of the technique is to improve pronunciation.

Since I am currently at level A2, I am looking for audio that is **a bit slower than the normal Spanish speech rate**, but not content for children. The difficulty of the content is otherwise not relevant (i.e. content at level C2 is also fine), as long as the speech is a bit slower than normal but otherwise quite natural. The content should also be entirely in Spanish and, of course, spoken by a native speaker of the language.

Additional clarification: I am not looking for a language course but (preferably) online content to complement the course materials that I have already. Podcasts may be fine, provided that they are not longer than 10 minutes (and audio intros and outtros are just a distraction).

Comment: Are you looking for courses like Assimil, or rather independent audio and podcasts?

Comment: @AML I am not looking for a language course but (preferably) online content to complement the course that I already have.

Answer (score 4):

Podcasts are probably going to be your best bet.

[News in Slow Spanish](https://www.newsinslowspanish.com/home) is a pretty classic one and one of the best options. [Automatic Spanish](http://www.espanolautomatico.com/) is another good one. [Fallo de Sistema](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/audios/fallo-de-sistema/) is a podcast that covers geeky stuff. It's not super slow, but it's not crazy fast either. Another one, about travel, from the same producer is [Nomadas](http://www.rtve.es/radio/nomadas/).

I would start with the first two and then eventually move on to the second two.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The thing with podcasts is that they are rather long and the audio intros are a bit of distraction.

Comment: Usually you can download them and edit out any parts that you don't like with a free program called Audacity. You can also break them up into custom sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In youtube, you have the option to change the speed of the videos you are watching.
You can either watch it at normal speed, faster or slower according to your preferences. They have the options 0.25* normal speed, 0.5, 0.75, Normal(1), 1.25, 1.5, and 2. I use it often when wanting to speed up the content of a talk and people are talking too slowly or making too many breaks.

It seams to be a good option for you, since you can search for whatever type of content you are interested on, and change the speed to you preference.
All it takes is selecting the wheel of preferences and then >speed at the bottom of the video and then choose your desired one.
You can try different speeds until you find one that is good for you to understand and repeat the words, but not too boring so that you fall asleep.

Youtube also has other cool features for someone who is learning a language, such as the possibility of seeing the transcript of the video you just watched, real-time with the video playing, and the option to move back and forward (pressing J will make you go back 10 secs and L go forward 10 secs)

More on [how to see transcripts of youtube videos and other hacks in this link](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-YouTube-hacks)

Hope it helps you,

Comment: Thanks, but I tried slowing down YouTube videos in the past and the resulting sound was awful. Speeding up the sound is never necessary for shadowing.